# Webpage Design: Font Size / Layout / Mobile Device

Tags: html, css, layout, font-size

I have the following webpage:

http://www.deutschschule.net/wb/default.asp?s=kaufen

It should work on mobile phones. Right now, it looks like it should, but there is the following problem: Some elements are too wide. The user should be able to just scroll horizontally, but that is not possible.

I tried to:

1) Remove:
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

And the font gets far to small. The user can zoom in but that is not desired.

2) Remove:
    `overflow-x: hidden;`

from the a.aResult element and the design gets messed up and the font is a bit too small.

3) Remove:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body {
       -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }
}
```

and there is no change. I wonder what this is actually supposed to do.

Basically, I would like to get exactly what I see right now, but there should be the possibility to scroll horizontally. Because the information on the far right is not that important, but should be still accessable.

Can you help me?

Comment: Give an example of the content being too wide please.

Comment: Hi Marcel,

here is a test page:

http://www.deutschschule.net/wb/test.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it is best to only scroll VERTICALLY, however if you wish to do this, you would simply need to declare a content container, something like `<div width="2000px"></div>` to extend the space past the right boundary.

Comment: <div width="2000px"></div>

didn't work. I tried:

<div style="width: 2000px;"></div>

but that gives me the same problem like removing #1 in my original post.

Comment: If you click the link in my original post:

http://www.deutschschule.net/wb/default.asp?s=kaufen

and then look at the source code, there is all the code html and the css in the head tag.

Comment: Ok yea what you need to do is encapsulate you content. Set body to have `width="2000px"` and then setup a `<div>` to encapsulate the content on the left, and another `<div>` to encapsulate content on the right. If you set their widths to a combined total of less than 2001px then they should sit side-by-side and you'll have your horizontal scroll.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. I have the following content:

p tag
a tag
a tag
...

p tag
a tag
a tag
a tag
...

Some of the a tags are wide and some are narrow. I would like that all the p and a tags are the same width. That is easy to do, but then the mobile phones seem to make the font extremely small to make all the content visible. But I want to keep the font size that I have right now. That means some of the a tags will not show the whole width, and for those few a tags the user would have to scroll horizontally.

Maybe I give up and just let the long ones break.

Comment: OOOH I see what you mean now, thanks for explaining. Don't set a % width for your ptags and atags, make them pixel-specific, that way they can't be bounded by the screen :)

Comment: But then the font is VERY small. I want to avoid this.

Comment: It doesn't work. I can't even describe all the problems I am facing now.

Comment: I'm sorry, don't have the time to give you a great explanation, all I can say is sit down and think about your structure some more. It looks like you're putting all the styling into the body and containers, when it's what's inside the containers that need to be styled.